# How to place a worldmap on a Node-Red dashboard

Tags: node-red

I have a Node-Red dashboard and want to place a worldmap in one of the tabs. Is that possible using a template node, iframe etc. ? Is there an example flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `node-red-contrib-web-worldmap` node includes an example flow for doing just this.

Look under `Import->Examples->node-red-contrib-web-worldmap`.

Comment: Did Import->Examples->web worldmap->Map in Dashboard. Got: Cannot GET /red/worldmap; I changed the URL to just /worldmap and can see the map now